# Get key of multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

For example, I have multidimensional array as below:

```
$array = array (
  0 => 
    array (
      'id' => '9',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '56475832.jpg'
    ),
  1 => 
    array (
      'id' => '8',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '20083622.jpg'
    ),
  2 => 
    array (
      'id' => '7',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '89001465.jpg'
    ),
  3 => 
    array (
      'id' => '6',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '47360232.jpg'
    ),
  4 => 
    array (
      'id' => '5',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '4876713.jpg'
    ),
  5 => 
    array (
      'id' => '4',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '5447392.jpg'
    ),
  6 => 
    array (
      'id' => '3',
      'gallery_id' => '2',
      'picture' => '95117187.jpg'
    )
);
```

How can I get key of `array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)`?

I have tried a lot of examples, but nothing has worked for me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is quite simple, you just need to use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/a4X0167I)

**EDIT** For your search task, this function should do the job:

```
function array_search_inner ($array, $attr, $val, $strict = FALSE) {
  // Error is input array is not an array
  if (!is_array($array)) return FALSE;
  // Loop the array
  foreach ($array as $key => $inner) {
    // Error if inner item is not an array (you may want to remove this line)
    if (!is_array($inner)) return FALSE;
    // Skip entries where search key is not present
    if (!isset($inner[$attr])) continue;
    if ($strict) {
      // Strict typing
      if ($inner[$attr] === $val) return $key;
    } else {
      // Loose typing
      if ($inner[$attr] == $val) return $key;
    }
  }
  // We didn't find it
  return NULL;
}

// Example usage
$key = array_search_inner($array, 'id', 9);
```

The fourth parameter `$strict`, if `TRUE`, will use strict type comparisons. So `9` will not work, you would have to pass `'9'`, since the values are stored as strings. Returns the key of the first occurence of a match, `NULL` if the value is not found, or `FALSE` on error. make sure to use a strict comparison on the return value, since `0`, `NULL` and `FALSE` are all possible return values and they will all evaluate to `0` if using loose integer comparisons.

Comment: Yes it's working, but, i need to search in array for example id=9, and get return id of array key, where's id = 9

Answer (score 7):

Try this , I think it will help you.

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $key.'<br/>';

    echo $value['id'].'<br/>';
    echo $value['gallery_id'].'<br/>';
    echo $value['picture'].'<br/><br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php ?

Convert your double dimensional array on your own:

```
$tmp = null
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  $tmp[] = $key;
}

print_r($tmp);
```

Answer (score 2):

sometimes it is to easy to find ;)

```
array_keys($array);
```

[array_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
function getKeys($array)
{
    $resultArr = array();
    foreach($array as $subArr) {
        $resultArr = array_merge($resultArr, $subArr);
    }        
    return array_keys($resultArr);
}
```

Comment: I think i didn't explain well my situation. For example, i'm looking for array where's id = 9, and i need a array key of that wheres 9, it would be 0, if i will be looking for id wheres 8, i will get 1