# Comparement index name of array fails / How to compare index name of array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, compare

I have a function which name is repeat.

I want to repeat array values if array key == 'repeat'

But my if ($k == 'repeat') comparement fails.

What is wrong with my comparement?

```
function repeat($schema, $repeat = array()){

    foreach($schema as $k => $v){
```

**if($k == 'repeat')**

3rd line does not working properly inside repeat function.

```
$schema = array(
    array(
        'tag' => 'div',
        'class' => 'lines',
        'repeat' => array(
            'tag' => 'div',
             array(
                'tag' => 'span',
                'style' => 'margin:10px; padding:10px',
                'key' => 'title',
            ),
            'key' => 'subject',
        )
    )
);

$repeat = array('Country Name' => 'Usa', 'City Name' => 'Newyork');

 // Recursive String Replace - recursive_array_replace(mixed, mixed, array);
function recursive_array_replace($find, $replace, $array){
    if (!is_array($array)){
        return str_replace($find, $replace, $array);
    }
    $newArray = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $newArray[$key] = recursive_array_replace($find, $replace, $value);
    }
    return $newArray;
}


function repeat($schema, $repeat = array()){
    foreach($schema as $k => $v){
        if($k == 'repeat'){
            foreach($repeat as $rk => $rv){
                $value = recursive_array_replace('title', $rk, $v);
                $value = recursive_array_replace('subject', $rv, $value);
                $info[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    //$schema = recursive_array_replace('repeat', $repeat, $schema);
    return $info;
}

print_r(repeat($schema, $repeat));
```

UPDATE1

Schema might be

```
$schema = array(
    'tag' => 'div',
    'class' => 'lines',
    array(
        'tag' => 'div',
        'class' => 'lines',
        'repeat' => array(
            'tag' => 'div',
             array(
                'tag' => 'span',
                'style' => 'margin:10px; padding:10px',
                'key' => 'title',
            ),
            'key' => 'subject',
             array(
                'tag' => 'span',
                'style' => 'margin:10px; padding:10px',
                'key' => 'title',
            ),
            'key' => 'subject',
        )
    )
);
```

UPDATE 2

```
$schema = array(
    array(
        'tag' => 'div',
        'class' => 'lines',
        array(
            'tag' => 'div',
            'repeat' => array(
                'tag' => 'div',
                 array(
                    'tag' => 'span',
                    'style' => 'margin:10px; padding:10px',
                    'key' => 'title',
                ),
                'key' => 'subject',
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Your `$schema` is nested array. You should modify it or iterate `foreach` of `$schema[0]`

Comment: $schema does not have constant value, always can change. $schema[0] might fail other situations. I need to compare index name of value

Comment: You may check `is_array($schema[0])` and if true assign `$schema` (your local variable) to `$schema[0]`.

Comment: @Voitcus there might be different arrays before and after 'repeat' tag is_array can fail.

Comment: I can't help you as I don't know what is your intention. The compartment fails because there is no "repeat" key in your `$schema` variable, but there exist one in `$schema[0]`. I didn't test validity of your code (that's why I don't post it as an answer)

Comment: After update of your question you are still able to get value of `$schema[0]['repeat']`

Comment: @Voitcus please check out 5th line of schema.. There is repeat key. You mean is it wrong way to compare? I did not understand.

Comment: @Voitcus it is true for update1 but not for update2

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion compartment fails because your `$schema` variable does not have `'repeat'` key.

You do `foreach` of all items in `$schema` variable, however (before update) there was only one item: the array. After the update there are three items, having keys `'tag'`, `'class'`, and one array which has no key, so it is automatically assigned to 0.

In both cases you are able to reach `'repeat'` key by referring to the 0th item of the array (via `$schema[0]['repeat']`).

If there are no other errors (I haven't checked) you should replace

```
foreach($schema as $k => $v){
```

to

```
foreach($schema[0] as $k => $v){
```

This will refer to the nested array; however, only in case there are no other numeric keys in the `$schema` array.

To ensure this you might for example first check which item is array, eg.

```
foreach($schema as $item){ // this is only an auxiliary loop
  if(is_array($item)){
    $new_schema=$item;
    break;
  }
}
```

and then move to main loop:

```
foreach($new_schema as $k => $v){
```

etc.

**After UPDATE 2**

You need to find your own way to access the `'repeat'` key. You may do this iteratively. In your code you access the wrong array, the first level, which has no "repeat" key, but you should go deeper.

Comment: How can I do this iteratively? Can you explain little bit more?

Comment: Instead of iterating in `repeat` function why won't you locate the `'repeat`' key? It's the only one you use. In the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) there are lots of examples of finding specific key in multi-dimensional array. Check also [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8940825/2088851)

Comment: Finding is ok. But I could not find to compare.