# Find the Key from multiple values array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key

I am trying to find the key of which one of the children items exists in. I have this array

```
$stdCurl    = array(
    'homepage'  => array('', '/', 'index.php', 'home', 'arxiki'),
    'blog'      => array('αρθρα', 'blog'),
    'post'      => array('αρθρο', '*post'),
    'products'  => array('προιοντα', 'products'),
    'product'   => array('προιον', 'product'),
    'portfolio' => array('portfolio', 'έργα'),
    'project'   => array('project', 'έργο')
);
```

User have selected the "post" value (marked with *). Now i want to find to which key "post" belongs to. I tried array_search, array_keys but can't make it work..I don't wont to loop, i was wondering if there is any built-in function for arrays for this..

Edited__

Basically i found the answer for my code, i just did not posted it because i wanted to know if there is really any way for this..
The reason i want this is because i parse the url and want to see if any of the keywords "index.php", "home", "product" etc exists in the url and if they exists i wanted to get the section these keywords belong to.

Let's say url is `http://domain.gr/gear-s3-samsung/product`.  I parse the url and explode it on "/", now i want to know if a keyword exists and if a keyword exists, return me the key that the keyword exists in from $stdCurl array.

```
foreach($this->stdCurl as $key => $value):
    foreach($value as $definedSection):
        if(in_array($definedSection, $this->urlStructure)):
            $this->pageKey = $key;
            $this->pageSection = $definedSection;
        else:
            continue;
        endif;
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Now i get they $key and shows me the section the keyword exists..But i wanted to know if i give you the value "αρθρο" how can i get the "post" key?

Comment: Please provide the expected result and any code you have already tried

Comment: Then show us the expected result at least

Comment: How to find the key of the array that "αρθρο" exists in? Without looping..

Answer (score 0):

```
$needle = '*post';

foreach ($stdCurl as $key => $value) {
    if (array_search($needle, $value))
        echo $key;
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to loop..I wanted something like array_search / array_diff..anyway, my bad, i found the answer..thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `key` function in combination with [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). The snippet:

```
$needle = 'αρθρο';
$pageKey = key(array_filter($stdCurl, function ($val) use ($needle) {
    return in_array($needle, $val);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is: To find "key" for the inner array search.

**Code:**

```
<?php

$stdCurl    = array(
  'homepage'  => array('', '/', 'index.php', 'home', 'arxiki'),
  'blog'      => array('αρθρα', 'blog'),
  'post'      => array('αρθρο', '*post'),
  'products'  => array('προιοντα', 'products'),
  'product'   => array('προιον', 'product'),
  'portfolio' => array('portfolio', 'έργα'),
  'project'   => array('project', 'έργο')
);

function array_search_key ($array, $val) {
  if (!is_array($array)){
    return false;
  }

  foreach ($array as $key => $inner_array) {
    if(in_array($val, $inner_array)){
      return $key;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

$key = array_search_key($stdCurl, 'προιον');

echo $key; //product

?>
```

***Quick Look:***

1. [Get key of multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940825/get-key-of-multidimensional-array)