# How do I get values inside this multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array as follows:

```
Array
(
 [lists] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 23ybdwhdwbed
                [name] => TEST
            (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => e223edsewed
                [name] => TEST 2
            (
    )
)
```

I want to access the ID & name variables using a foreach loop.

I'm using this:

```
$x = 0;
foreach($lists as $list){

    $listId = $list[$x]['id'];
    $listName = $list[$x]['name'];

    echo"$x | $listId $listName <br />";

$x++;
}
```

For some strange reason, I can only get the value of the first $listId & $name, not the second $listId or $name.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get key of multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940825/get-key-of-multidimensional-array)

Comment: your arraye-example seems to be wrong. you have 6 opening parathesis but only 2 closing ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array you posted is wrong because it's missing closing `)`, so correct that (I think that is ***TYPO*** mistake)

After that you need to do it like below:-

```
foreach($lists['lists'] as $key=> $list){
   $listId = $list['id'];
   $listName = $list['name'];
   echo "$key | $listId $listName <br />";
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/846464

***Or an one-liner code:-***

```
foreach($lists['lists'] as $key=> $list){
  echo "$key | ".$list['id']." ".$list['name']." <br />";
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/846465

Answer (score 2):

You're assuming that you still need to provide the key for each child element.  This is not the case.

try

```
foreach($lists as $list){

    $listId = $list['id'];
    $listName = $list['name'];

    $listId $listName <br />";

}
```

the `foreach()` will iterate over them in turn.

if you do need the index number, do this instead.

```
foreach($lists as $x => $list){
```

where `$x` is the index.

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` iterates the first, not the second level of your multi  dimensional array.

Since the first level only holds the `lists` array as one and only element the loop only executes once.

Pass the `lists` key to the `foreach` instead like so:

```
$x = 0;
foreach($lists['lists'] as $list) {
    echo "$x | " . $list['id'] . " " . $list['name'] . "<br />"; 
    ++$x;
}
```

Also note how in here I reference the list elements by name to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I think those numerical indexed will just confuse you so try this instead:

```
$my_array = array(array("id" => "23ybdwhdwbed", "name" => "TEST"), array("id" => "e223edsewed", "name" => "TEST 2"));
```

To access the values: use:

```
foreach($my_array as $my_data){
    echo "ID:" . $my_data["id"];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "NAME:" .$my_data["name"];
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do:

```
foreach($lists['list'] as $listKey=>$listValue){
   $listId = $listValue['id'];
   $listName = $listValue['name'];
   echo"$listKey | $listId : $listName <br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I fixed your array structure to work, this is also dynamic so it does not matter how many array you have 0 -> above

```
       $array = array(
                      'lists' => array(
                                      '0' => array(
                                                    'id' => '23ybdwhdwbed',
                                                    'name' => 'TEST 1'
                                                    ),
                                      '1' => array(
                                                    'id' => 'e223edsewed',
                                                    'name' => 'TEST 2'
                                                   )
                                      )
    );

      foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        for($ctr = 0; $ctr < count($value); $ctr++){
             echo 'ID: ' . $value[$ctr]['id'] . '<br>';
             echo 'Name: : ' . $value[$ctr]['name'] . '<br><br>';
        }
      }
```