# Laravel preserve group keys in collection serialization

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel v.5.8:

I want to group each child relation *budgets* and json serialize it.

```php
$monthbudgets = \App\BudgetMonth::where('month', $curmonth)->with("budgets")->get();
    foreach ($monthbudgets as $month) {
        $month->budgets = $month->budgets->groupBy("customer_id");
    }
dd($monthbudgets[8]);
```

which will return:

```php
//laravel collection of "budgets"
...[
    1 => [
        0 => []
        1 => []
    ],
    5 => [
        0 => []
    ]
]...
```

but using `dd($monthbudgets[8]->jsonSerialize())`, it will return:

```php
//array of "budgets"
...[
    0 => []
    1 => []
    2 => []
]...
```

Looks like it flattens it and removes the keys (1, 5).

I'm also open to suggestions for minimizing the grouping loop. I tried

```php
->with(["budgets" => function ($query) {
    $query->groupBy("customer_id");
}])->get();
```

which will result in

`Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'budgets.id' isn't in GROUP BY (...)`

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940825/get-key-of-multidimensional-array

Comment: When returning a json response you can just return the collection and it will be serialized by default. For keys try using [keyBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-keyby) and maybe [transform](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-transform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's `jsonSerialize` will call `toArray`:

```
// Model.php
public function toArray()
{
    return array_merge($this->attributesToArray(), $this->relationsToArray());
}
```

which merges the attributes and then the relations which makes it overwrite the attribute you've set.

You can set the relation with `setRelation`

```
foreach ($monthbudgets as $month) {
    $month->setRelation('budgets', $month->budgets->groupBy("customer_id"));
}
```